# Swift: 2 consecutive closures/blocks

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

According to the docs here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files-progress/iOS

this is the suggested syntax to handle file saving with a completion block and progressBlock.

```
let str = "Working at Parse is great!"
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let file = PFFile(name:"resume.txt", data:data)
file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  // Handle success or failure here ...
}, progressBlock: {
  (percentDone: Int) -> Void in
  // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
}
```

However, XCode 6.2 throws this error:
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

on this line:

```
}, progressBlock: {
```

Anyone know how to properly utilize the progressBlock in this scenario?

Edit 1:
Here's the sample in Obj C:

```
NSData *data = [@"Working at Parse is great!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"resume.txt" data:data];
[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  // Handle success or failure here ...
} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
  // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
}];
```

Edit 2:

Another attempt, different error:

[image: Another attempt, another error]

Edit 3:
Original code, but with CInt per a comment suggestion

[image]

Comment: By Xcode 6.2 do you mean Xcode 6 beta 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a class in Objective C with the method signature:

```
- (void)saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(void(^)(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error))block progressBlock:(void(^)(int percentDone))progressBlock;
```

I can call it like so from Swift:

```
let file = Test()
file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("1")
    }, progressBlock: { (percentage: CInt) -> Void in
        NSLog("2")
    })
```

Comment: `block:` may be unnecessary as it is the first parameter.

Comment: "Extra argument 'block' in call"

Comment: Try without "block:".

Comment: "Extra argument in call"

Comment: It's interesting, it works for me. Your original code.

Comment: You can actually build successfully?

Comment: Yeah. The only difference is I used `CInt` as the param for the progress percent done.

Comment: Check out my Edit 3 in the original post... that's what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing () around method arguments. Should be:

```
file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    // Handle success or failure here ...
}, progressBlock: {
    (percentDone: Int) -> Void in
    // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
})
```

(Note: when calling Objective-C from Swift code, Xcode translates (in code completion) `int` into `CInt`, and `NSInteger` into `Int`).

Comment: Extra argument 'progressBlock' in call