# saveInBackgroundWithBlock with progress doesn't work in Swift under Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The following code I got from parse.com website doesn't work:

```
let str = "Working at Parse is great!"
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let file = PFFile(name:"resume.txt", data:data)
file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  // Handle success or failure here ...
}, progressBlock: {
  (percentDone: Int) -> Void in
  // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
}
```

The error message is:

> Cannot invoke 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of
>   type '((Bool, NSError?) -> Void?, progressBlock: (Int) -> Void?)'

I tried different combination but none works. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Since the PFFile wants 2 closure blocks, things are a little different. See this answer, though, as I think it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548837/swift-2-consecutive-closures-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IOS 8.3 the following snippet works:

```
let str = "Working at Parse is great!"
    let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let file = PFFile(name:"resume.txt", data:data!)

    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // Handle success or failure here ...
        if succeeded {
            println("Save successful")
        } else {
            println("Save unsuccessful: \(error?.userInfo)")
        }

        }, progressBlock: { (percentDone: Int32) -> Void in
        // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
    })
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Still got compiling error:
ViewController.swift:30:23: Cannot invoke 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool, NSError?) -> Void, progressBlock: (Int32) -> Void)'

Comment: Here is the working code in a modified ParseSwiftStarter project for Xcode 6.3: https://bitbucket.org/jonathanburris/parseswiftstarterproject

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and mrbcg's way worked for me.

To show the progress: add and connect the `IBOutlet` in the Storyboard
`@IBOutlet weak var UploadProgressView: UIProgressView`.

Then edit the following:

```
progressBlock: { (percentDone: Int32) -> Void in
            // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
            let percentProgress = Float(percentDone) / 100.0
            let animated = percentProgress != 0
            self.UploadProgressView.setProgress(percentProgress, animated: animated)
    })

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UploadProgressView.setProgress(0, animated: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```